# Interpreting the output of an ANCOVA as regards to the descriptive statistics

Tags: interpretation, descriptive-statistics, ancova

I'm quite annoyed by the outputs of one my analyses.

I'm conducting a repeated measures ANCOVA including two IVs, one DV, and two covariates. My issue is that when I include my two covariates, the effect of IV1 is not significant (while it is highly significant when I exclude either of the two covariates or both). I easily understand that the effect disappears when controlling for the two variables included as covariates. My worry is that when I report percentage scores (means and SDs) for IV1, the difference, although not significant when including the two covariates is quite spectacular : for instance (percentage score) Level 1 = 72.1, SD = 19.2 ; Level 2 = 43.2, SD = 31.2.

This is what I should write :

"[...] suggest that participants endorse negative conclusions (M = 43.2, SD = 31.2) as much as positive ones (M = 72.1, SD = 19.2)"

My question is probably a naive one, but wouldn't anyone question about this? (that is, that the descriptive difference is descriptively huge albeit not significant) ? I feel uncomfortable saying that participants do the same either the level while descriptive results are so different (although I appreciate that it is how it should be reported). What do you think ?